# how to select all files with dates on their names?

Tags: file, date, batch-file

I have multiple files such as qulogscan_141201.txt (year month day)
 am trying to create a batch which will pick that file and find "notloaded" inside it, what I have done so far is this:

```
Echo NOTLOADED
Echo\
set yy=%date:~-2%
set mm=%date:~-7,2%
set dd=%date:~-10,2%

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem Assemble the list of line numbers
set numbers=
set "folder=J:\Console\Output_Del\sscmex\qulogscan_%yy%%mm%%dd%.txt"
for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /I /N /C:"NOTLOADED" "%folder%"') do (
   set /A after=%%a+3
   set "numbers=!numbers!!after!: "
)
rem Search for the lines
(for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" "%folder%" ^| findstr /B "%numbers%"') do echo %%b)
```

how can I do to make it select the file qulogscan_.txt ignoring the datastamps without renaming it ?

Comment: Have you tried `dir /b qulogscan_*` as the input in your `FOR` loop?

Comment: where would I inset that line?